# Is there an Erlang os:cmd equivalent that takes a list of strings instead of a single command?

Tags: erlang

Is there a Erlang call where I can do `Retval = subprocess:call(["cmd", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"])`?

If I'm building a complex command to execute, with os:cmd/1 it is easy to make escaping mistakes. Compare to Python's subprocess.call() method where I pass in a list of strings and know that it is passed verbatim to the subprocess, nothing mangled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I have come up with.

```
-module(mycmd).
-export([cmd/2]).

cmd(Cmd, Args) ->
    Tag = make_ref(), 
    {Pid, Ref} = erlang:spawn_monitor(fun() ->
            Rv = cmd_sync(Cmd, Args),
            exit({Tag, Rv})
        end),
    receive
        {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, {Tag, Data}} -> Data;
        {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, Reason} -> exit(Reason)
    end.

cmd_sync(Cmd, Args) ->
    P = open_port({spawn_executable, os:find_executable(Cmd)}, [
            binary, use_stdio, stream, eof, {args, Args}]),
    cmd_receive(P, []).

cmd_receive(Port, Acc) ->
    receive
        {Port, {data, Data}} -> cmd_receive(Port, [Data|Acc]);
        {Port, eof}          -> {ok, lists:reverse(Acc)}
    end.
```

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays you can do `open_port({spawn_executable, Command}, [{args, [A1, ..., An]}])`, but there is no convenient wrapper for this in the os module yet. You could take the code for `os:cmd/1` and tweak it to use `spawn_executable`. Check the docs for `erlang:open_port/2` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do `os:cmd(string:join(["cmd", "arg1", "arg2"], " "))` ?

Comment: That does not address the problem, which is that the string given to os:cmd/1 will be processed by a shell. This will expand things in a system-dependent way. For example, os:cmd("echo 'Hello'") will pass Hello to the echo command without the single quotes. It is hard to get this sort of thing right so that the program gets the exact same argument strings that you have on the Erlang side. You need a way to run the program without a shell as middle-man.